# How to load resources in Tomcat via Java File api

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have to use a library that accepts path to a directory and loads it via `File(path);`. What should be the path in tomcat webapp context ?

I always work with classpaths, but this API is really not thought through...

I don't have experience with java execution context in tomcat, but it seems to me a bad idea doing something like this

```
System.getProperty("catalina.base") + "webapps/app/WEB-INF/classes/profiles"
```

Does tomcat provides java execution (AKA $PWD) path for resources in application context ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ServletContext#getRealPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) to convert a webapp-relative path to an absolute disk file system path. Given your example, the following should do:

```
String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classes/profiles");
File file = new File(path);
// ...
```

Note that this requires that the WAR is expanded, otherwise it will return `null`. Tomcat by default expands the WAR, but some other servletcontainers/configs don't. Keep this in mind with regard to portability.

Comment: @Vladimir Dyuzhev: you missed the last paragraph of the answer and the fact that OP uses Tomcat? Or did you just love unicorns? :)

Comment: I simply regret seeing globally wrong answers even when they are locally correct. :)

Comment: @erica: Vladimir has deleted the comment, but the reason boils down to that not all containers expand the WAR and that this is configureable in Tomcat, exactly as I covered in the last paragraph of my answer. Pretty ridiculous, yes :)

Comment: Correct... until the application is deployed to Weblogic, or to a production Tomcat installation where WAR expanding is disabled by the will of operations support.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was warning for :)

Comment: Don't you think it is a dangerous practice to give advises like that? ;) I once had to patch one commercial application for exactly this reason. :-E

Comment: Not if it is documented properly. I'd rather patch the 3rd party API, yes, also in OP's case.

Comment: I assume he wants the resource to live in the WAR structure for simplicity of version control/deployment.  If the app has to run in an unexploded environment you could create a temp file using File.createTempFile() and copy the contents from ServletContext.getResourceAsStream().   Then pass the library to path to the temp file.

Comment: @ericacm: the OP needs to pass a **directory**, not a file.

Comment: right.. he could copy out the whole directory to a temp directory!  :) just kidding, that's ridiculous..

Comment: @ericacm: it's not trivial to crawl a directory in the classpath without using `File#listFiles()` because it's not expanded.

Comment: You don't need to crawl "directory" in classpath. You store a whole JAR as a resource, get it from classpath and unpack using ZIP API.

Answer (score 2):

Application resources do NOT necessary exist on file system, therefore the search from context path approach is simply wrong.

You should provide an external configuration to your application (a property file or DB), where you should define the path depending on environment.

Suggested order of searching for configuration:

1. System.properties: -Dmy.configuration=/home/tomcat/my.properties
2. System environment: MY_CONFIGURATION=/home/tomcat/my.properties
3. Default value: ./my.properties (for Tomcat it is usually bin folder, but not guaranteed)
4. Fail and complain.

Comment: Good to know, but this app is dedicated to Tomcat

Comment: Right. Let people who come after you clean up your mess.